# Problem with javascript getelementbyid

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

well I have 3 LinkButton

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit Record" OnClientClick='ControlVisible();'/>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSave" runat="server" Text="Save" Visible="false" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" Visible="false"  />
```

when I'll click to lnkEdit button lnkSave and lnkCancel buttons must unvisible

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function ControlVisible() {


        var Edit = document.getElementById("lnkEdit"); 
        var Save = document.getElementById("lnkSave");
        var Cancel = document.getElementById("lnkCancel");

        Edit.visible = false;
        Save.visible = true;
        Cancel.visible = true;

    }

</script>
```

But when I'll cLick Edit **LinkButton** : var Edit = document.getElementById("lnkEdit"); here comes Null, can not retrive Control's ID

what the proble?

Answer (score 5):

You have to use another alternative:

```
var Edit = document.getElementById("<%= lnkEdit.ClientID %>"); 
var Save = document.getElementById("<%= lnkSave.ClientID %>");
var Cancel = document.getElementById("<%= lnkCancel.ClientID %>");
```

You can also use the ASP.NET AJAX $get method, which is a shortcut for document.getElementById.

Comment: yes it works but dose not effect to controls, all this buttons are visible :(

Answer (score 3):

When you set `Visible` false on web control, it means that it never reach the browser. As far as the browser knows, those controls don't exist.

So first make them hidden using CSS instead by changing `Visible="false"` to `style="display: none;"` - the effect will be the same.

Next, change the code to this, as others also suggested:

```
var oEdit = document.getElementById("<%=lnkEdit.ClientId%>"); 
var oSave = document.getElementById("<%=lnkSave.ClientId%>");
var oCancel = document.getElementById("<%=lnkCancel.ClientId%>");
oEdit.style.display = "";
oSave.style.display = "";
oCancel.style.display = "";
```

Comment: I tried it But not works
oEdit i got something like this ctl00$MainContent$lnkEdit
oSave - ctl00$MainContent$lnkSave
oCancel - ctl00$MainContent$lnkCancel

ids are different is not it?

Comment: @west sorry no idea what you mean. The `ctl00$MainContent$lnkEdit` is name, not ID and it's not relevant. Try adding `alert(oEdit);` and you should see alert dialog with "[object]" - keep us updated please.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET will generate its own HTML ids. If you want to force your own custom IDs to be generated, you can specify the ID using the "clientID" attribute:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" clientID="lnkEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit Record" OnClientClick='ControlVisible();'/>
```

Answer (score 2):

ASP .NET automatically includes the IDs of the parent elements when generating an ID for an element. The generated HTML will have IDs following this kind of format: `ctl00$MainContent$txtSymbol`. So, the default DOM function `getElementById` won't find an element if you only use the last ID.

Source Element:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSymbol">
```

HTML generated:

```
<input type="text" id="ctl00_MainContent_txtSymbol" name="ctl00$MainContent$txtSymbol">
```

You can create a helper jQuery function which takes care of this. The next function created by [Rick Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/42319.aspx) does the job:

```
function $$(id, context) {  
    var el = $("#" + id, context);  
    if (el.length < 1) {  
        el = $("[id$=_" + id + "]", context);
    }
    return el;  
}
```

You can use it like this to find your element:

```
$$("txtSymbol")
```

Comment: yes you are right I get like this ctl00$MainContent$lnkEdit
Can you explain me more clearly about this function?

what parameter do i pass to context?

Comment: You can pass another element to context, a parent element, in that way you restrict your search to only that sub tree  of the DOM. For example: $$("txtSymbol", $$("nearestPanel)) , in the case of txtSymbol living inside nearestPanel, txtSymbol would be a child of nearest panel. This is to provide a little bit more of information and not search in the whole DOM tree.

Answer (score 1):

Are You sure it's about his line:

```
var Edit = document.getElementById("lnkEdit");
```

and not about this one:

```
Edit.visible = false;
```

Not sure which browser accepts visible property directly on HTML element, but try to use this instead:

```
Edit.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

or

```
Edit.style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: My be, but var Edit here comes nothing Null

Answer (score 1):

If the controls are inside a container, the id of the container will be prepended to the if of the conbtrol to create a client id that is unique.

You can use the `ClientID` property to find out the generated id:

```
var Edit = document.getElementById("<%=lnkEdit.ClientId%>"); 
var Save = document.getElementById("<%=lnkSave.ClientId%>");
var Cancel = document.getElementById("<%=lnkCancel.ClientId%>");
```